# How to get skip 3rd party progress web page and get final result page without being directed after form submission?

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, curl, cross-domain

I have a homepage. After user submits their form data, I would like to first send the data to 3rd party server (no API, they only provide web page, meaning I submit form to 3rd party our service provider process.aspx page). After get the result back, I'd like to use part of the content, render it and use on my only web page. The default behavior of form submission to the 3rd party server is after I submit the form to them, they redirect me to their progress web page. Because the form processing takes long, user sees this progress page before the final search result (result.aspx) comes back.

In order to only use 3rd party final search result page without being redirected, I tried following ways, but none of them worked out due to different reasons.

1. on client side, I used hidden iframe, but due to iframe security constraint, containing page (my home page) cannot use javascript to detect when the iframe page finish loaded with final result page, as domain is not the same (cross domain communication is not allowed using iframe)
2. I send the form data to our server, using curl to submit form to 3rd party web server from our server. The problem is the result curl returned is the progress page, while curl cannot execute javascript as browser (progress page has javascript), I couldn't exec the progress page to get final price page.
3. using Ajax on client side, same problem, cross domain communication is not allowed for "Access-Control-Not-Allowed" as the request page and home page are not from same origin.
4. (not efficient, but an option) using a browserless tool like htmlunit on server, so I could get final price page using a java program. But the problem is I are not allowed to run java program on my web server (provided by web service provider).

Is it possible to achieve what I'd like to do at all? Desperate now...Any suggestions?

Comment: Post code as well . Read the faq and about us to post question

Comment: Have you contacted the 3rd party? It seems like they really don't want you to do this, or they'd provide an API.

Comment: they provide API, but that's different service they provide. And it takes a lot more effort than using their web page package, i will do redirect after fetching and show the search result in my page anyways, so this is easier.

Comment: Shail, thanks for your response. I'm looking for solution. i don't have working code.